# Swapping fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

My main view is made of 2 fragments

```
gfs = new GalleriesFragment();
gf = new GalleryFragment();

FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.frame1,gfs);
ft.add(R.id.frame2,gf);
ft.commit();
```

On a event I want to

- replace the frame1 fragment by the fragment in the frame 2.
- replace the frame2 fragment by a new fragment

(something like the gmail apps)

So I do this :

```
ImageFragment ig = new ImageFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = null;
transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(gf.getId(), ig);
transaction.replace(gfs.getId(), gf);
transaction.addToBackStack("remove1");
transaction.commit();
```

The first replace works, but the second throw an error :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment
>   GalleryFragment{41034f18 #1 id=0x7f060008}: was 2131099656 now
>   2131099655

I tried different combination, by removing then adding fragments but without succes.

Is it possible to do this in only one transaction ?

thanks !

Comment: Why not create a new fragment with a parceable of the old fragments data.

Answer (score 0):

A fragment may only have one parent, and you are trying to move the fragment from one parent to another.

I've never done anything like this, but it might be possible if you detach (not remove, but detach so it still exists) the fragment from the original parent container first and then replace it into the other.

And honestly, I would use the direct id (R.id.whatever) rather than trying to use `getId()`... but that's just my personal bias.